# In C#, Javascript/script is unable to read class attribute

Tags: javascript, c#

```
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" 
 src="<%= Url.Content("Scripts/Web/Book.js") %>"></script>
```

I am using C# and it does not seem to read 'attribute class is not a valid attribute of element script' The jquery used is jquery-1.10.2.min.js. Anyone can help??

In Book.js,

```
   include: function(array, item) {
        if (!ExtArray.contains(array, item)) {
            array.push(item);
        }
    },

ExtArray = Ext.Array = {
 // codes...
};
```

Comment: How exactly do you produce the output in C#? There must be a way to trick it into outputting what it thinks is invalid.  But why do you need a class on a script tag anyway?

Comment: How are you trying to read the attribute? Accessing DOM properties and attributes can be a little messy, jQuery got it wrong for quite some time and it depends on whether you're using *prop* or *attr* for access to non–standard attributes and how they are set.

Comment: @Thilo Because it was already working previously. But I think there was a mess in codes. Therefore, I was looking into where I messed up be it in accidentally removing/adding any other codes...

Comment: @RobG it is reading the attribute from another .js file. It definitely is working previously...

Comment: Re-reading your question, it seems that you get the error when reading from the DOM (in Javascript), not when creating the HTML (in C#). Please show the JS code you use to do that.

Comment: @Thilo I added the codes above

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! I uncomment many commented lines(//), which are not suppose to display and it messed up. Thanks all for the help!